# Drive api: file.list returning inconsistent result when corpus='user'

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I'm using Drive Api on appengine, authenticating with a service account.
On my Drive space I have many documents created with my personal user and shared with the service account.

```
+--_folderA
   +-- fileA1
   +-- fileA2
   +-- fileA3
   +--_folderB
      +-- fileB1
      +-- fileB2
```

If I call file.list with **corpus='domain'** I correctly obtain all the files shared with the service account.

```
response = service.files().list(q="",
    spaces='drive',
    corpus='domain',
    fields='nextPageToken,
    files(id, name)',
    pageToken=page_token).execute()

RESULT: folderA, folderB, fileA1, fileA2, fileA3, fileB1, fileB2
```

But if I call file.list with **corpus='user'** I obtain only a subset of the files that are shared with the service account.

```
response = service.files().list(q="",
    spaces='drive',
    corpus='user',
    fields='nextPageToken,
    files(id, name)',
    pageToken=page_token).execute()
RESULT: fileA2, fileB1
```

The behavior is particularly strange because I can not find any criteria to which some files are returned and some are not. In fact all the files shared with the service account have the same properties.
Moreover, if I add a **query with a clause on parents folder (and corpus='user')**, I see more files and this looks strange to me, since I'm narrowing down the search space.

```
response = service.files().list(q="folderA_ID in parents",
    spaces='drive',
    corpus='user',
    fields='nextPageToken,
    files(id, name)',
    pageToken=page_token).execute()
RESULT: fileA1, fileA2, fileA3
```

I obtain the same result using Java and Python.

Comment: Please show the relevant code, in particular the code which contains the various queries you are running against Google Drive.

Comment: If it's your intention to see your own files, don't use a Service Account. Simply authenticate directly to your own account. Life then becomes much simpler.

Comment: I added the code in original post.
I need to use a Service Account because I'm working on a daemon.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's a daemon or not. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766912/how-do-i-authorise-an-app-web-or-installed-without-user-intervention-canonic for the steps on how to auth background apps. Service Accounts are not intended for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

Google has [explained](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140153526#comment3) why this happens:

> The behavior when making a Files.List request in which corpora parameter is set to "user", is to return all the files from MyDrive and also the files shared with you, even if they are files inside a Shared Drive. **But there is an exception to this when the requesting user have permissions on the Shared Drive (Manager, Viewer, Contributor, etc), in this case, the Files.List request won't retrieve the files in the Shared Drive (despite having permissions for all the files inside it) unless the user have had any interaction with the file (Have created/opened/shared to other person, the file).**
>
> This exception about the above behavior is not stated in the official documentation. I opened an internal issue about this so the documentation can be updated.
>
> For the behavior you're expecting, you can set the corpora parameter to "allDrives" which will retrieve you all the files from MyDrive, the files shared with you and all the files in the Shared Drives you have permissions to.

In my opinion this is confusing, but I suppose the intent of this from an API perspective is to allow the API to return files that are *relevant* to the user, instead of all files the user *has access to*. When the user is a Manager, Viewer, Contributer, etc. on the shared drive, the latter list might be quite large, and the user may well not be interested in a large portion of the content.

Answer (score 0):

A service account has its own Google Drive account.  So there is a difference between files it owns and files that where shared with it.

> [Acceptable values are](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list#parameters): 
>  
>      "domain": Files shared to the user's domain.
>  
>       "user": Files owned by or shared to the user. (default)

When you request `domain` you are asking to see all the files it has access to. Those being your files.   When you say `users` you are asking for files that the service account personally owns.   check the [permissions](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions) on the files my guess is you will get some insight into why some files are returning and others aren't.

More info on [domain](https://support.google.com/a/answer/3187967?hl=en)

Comment: I checked permissions, ownership and all the possibile file attributes very carefully.
If the problem was related to the permissions, then adding the clause on the parent folder I could not see the more files:
`corpus=user -> fileA2, fileB1`
but
`corpus=user and parent=folderA -> fileA1, fileA2, fileA3`

Comment: I have this same problem with a regular user, so its not a problem limited to service accounts. For example, I have a folder in a Team Drive with 20 files in it, all created by my user and all owned by me. When I use my user to list it with `corpora=user`, I get only 3 files. With `corpora=drive`, I get all of them. The only difference (IIRC) is that the 3 files were created directly in the team drive, and the others were created in "My Drive" and moved into the Team Drive. However, replicating this scenario with a test file does not show the same behavior.